# How to capture history of changes in the VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce, history-tracking

I have a visual force page which enables users to change records. This is enabled using an input field where user can make the changes and then hit "Save" button to make changes in the back-end Object table. However, business requires that I can capture what were the changes made by the users (in terms of the old value and the new value of the changed record). Is this possible through Visual Force?

Following is my Controller code:

```
public List<User_Stats__c> getSalesRepsHist(){
    Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
    Sales_rep=[Select Sales_Rep__c, Month__c, Rental_Revenue_Goal__c From User_Stats__History];
    return Sales_Rep;
}
```

Basically I want to see that for which Sales Rep and for which month were the goals changed. What was the old value and the new value.

Please help. I will be happy to share the code if required. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use [field tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history.htm&language=en_US)? I think this is exactly that what you need.

Comment: For detailed instructions, see https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history_for_standard_objects.htm&language=en_US and http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history_for_custom_objects.htm&language=en_US

Comment: I have added a snippet of the controller code where I want to access the history in a particular manner. Please help with the code..

Comment: OP looks to have reposted the question here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24358/how-to-display-the-history-result