# How to display the history result?

Tags: visualforce

I have enabled history in my custom object. I want to extract only those record which have been altered and want to order them by modified time. I have history enabled only on variable called "Rental_Revenue_Goal__c"

Following is my code:

VF

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!SalesRepsHist}" var="rephist" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" align="center" bgcolor="#F5FFFA">
        <apex:column headerValue="Sales Rep" value="{!rephist.Sales_Rep__c}">
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Goal" value="{!rephist.Rental_Revenue_Actual__c}">
        </apex:column>                   
        <apex:column headerValue="Old" value="{!rephist.OldValue}">
        </apex:column>                   
        <apex:column headerValue="New" value="{!rephist.NewValue}">
        </apex:column>                   
    </apex:dataTable>
```

Controller:

```
public List<User_Stats__c> getSalesRepsHist(){
    Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
    Sales_rep=[Select Sales_Rep__c, Rental_Revenue_Goal__c, (select OldValue, NewValue From Histories) From User_Stats__c where MONTH__C = '10' and Year__c = '2013' and Sales_Rep__c =: OSR and Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Sales_Rep__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null];
    return Sales_Rep;
}
```

Please help me with the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the issue:

`{!SalesRepsHist}` is a list of `User_Stats__c` but each `User_Stat__c` contains a relationship list of old/new value field histories. Thus, your VF table needs to be a nested table like this:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!SalesRepsHist}" var="rep" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" align="center" bgcolor="#F5FFFA">
    <apex:column headerValue="Sales Rep" value="{!rep.Sales_Rep__c}">
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Goal" value="{!rep.Rental_Revenue_Actual__c}">
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="History">
     <apex:dataTable value="{!rep.histories}" var="fldHist">                   
       <apex:column headerValue="Old" value="{!fldhist.OldValue}">
       </apex:column>                   
       <apex:column headerValue="New" value="{!fldhist.NewValue}">
       </apex:column>                   
     </apex:dataTable>
    </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

BTW - the controller as written above won't compile as Sales_rep is not declared. Replace with something like this: (I added the date ordering using descending sequence)

```
public List<User_Stats__c> getSalesRepsHist(){
Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
List<User_Stats__c> statsList = [Select Sales_Rep__c, Rental_Revenue_Goal__c, (select createdDate, OldValue, NewValue From Histories where field = 'Rental_Revenue_Goal__c' order by createdDate desc) From User_Stats__c where MONTH__C = '10' and Year__c = '2013' and Sales_Rep__c =: OSR and Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Sales_Rep__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null];
return statsList;
}
```

With the combination of the two, you can display a table of any number of sales reps and their field history.   It might also be useful to show the date modified in the table (`CreatedDate` in `Histories`)

Comment: hi Corp1645. In the code above, how can I filter history for only the changes made on that date? i.e. createdDate = Today()??

Comment: Robin - a useful reference for using date filters can be found here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm so the where clause would be `createdDate = TODAY`